# Ethminer "No GPU device with sufficient memory was found"

Tags: ethminer, gpu, batch

**I have two Sapphire Nitro+ RX 480 OC cards. When only one is inserted into a PCIe slot, I am able to mine ETH with no issues. When both are inserted into PCIe slots, my terminal returns:**

"No GPU device with sufficient memory was found. Can't GPU mine. Remove the -G argument."

**This happens despite my devices.bat file returning:**
Listing OpenCL devices.
FORMAT: [deviceID] deviceName
[0] Ellesmere
        CL_DEVICE_TYPE: GPU
        CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 8589934592
        CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 4244635648
        CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 256
[1] Ellesmere
        CL_DEVICE_TYPE: GPU
        CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 8589934592
        CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 4244635648
        CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 256"

**My .bat file for Ethminer is:**
start cmd /k "cd miner & ethminer -G -F http://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/0x51df06C26B3FA5bb0509015Ef3fC4D815f1f02F2"

**Update:** Both cards work perfectly with Folding@Home, so it is not a hardware issue. There is something going wrong with my Ethminer execution. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `--opencl-platform 1` (2, 3, etc) before the `-G` key should help.